# What is a good way to add an Actor as a userdata type for a Box2d body?

Tags: libgdx, rendering, box2d, actor

I've created my actor and my body(`Box2D`) in Android Studio, but seem to be having a problem rendering it.

I set the `body.setUserDataType(actor)` before I add the actor to my `stage` object. Should I set the `textureRegion` that is drawn on the actor's `draw` class method as a userdata Type or use my actor as a userdata Type like I am doing at the moment? I believe I have to cast the parameter of this method call like this: `body.setUserDataType((NameOfActorsClass)actor)`.

Comment: How did you decided to use box2d physics with stage, really curious :O

Comment: Just seemed like a logical thing to do. @-Kush